# I'm trying to get what I print and add it to a list to print out as an employee payroll

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to make a list that takes the input from the user and adds it to the list to be printed later when the user asks for it as a part of my final in an intro to python class.the program is supposed to be a payroll calculator

I've tried making an empty list named employees and appending the printout to the list but it won't accept the user input

```
employees = []

while yes_no == 1:
    emp_name = str(input("please enter the employees name"))
    num1 = int(input("Please enter the hours you worked "))
    num2 = int(input("Please enter your hourly wage  "))
    print("Employee", emp_name, "Worked ", num1, "hours, and are paid", num2, "$ per hour. Making your salary",
    num1 * num2, "$")
    employees.append("Employee", emp_name, "Worked ", num1, "hours, and are paid", num2,
                     "$ per hour. Making your salary",
                     num1 * num2, "$")

    yes = int(input("If you would like to calculate more employees salaries yes or no "))
    emp_name = str(input("please enter the employees name"))
    num1 = int(input("Please enter the hours you worked "))
    num2 = int(input("Please enter your hourly wage  "))
    print("Employee", emp_name, "Worked ", num1, "hours, and are paid", num2, "$ per hour. Making your salary"
    , num1 * num2, "$")
    employees.append(str("Employee", emp_name, "Worked ", num1, "hours, and are paid", num2,
                     "$ per hour. Making your salary",
                     num1 * num2, "$"))
    yes_no = int(input("If you would like to calculate more employees salaries type 1 for yes or or type 0 for no "))

    if yes_no == 0:
        break

print("Thanks for using my calculator, ", name)
```

I expected the list to be filled with the inputs but all that happened was my IDE said that append is expecting 1 argument and it got 9.

Answer (score 1):

The bit

```
employees.append("Employee", emp_name, "Worked ", num1, "hours, and are paid", num2,
                 "$ per hour. Making your salary",
                 num1 * num2, "$")
```

is attempting to call `append` with 9 different pieces of data (each separated by a `,`). If you're thinking of how `print` takes multiple objects separated by `,`s and concatenates them, that's a behavior specific to `print` and a few other functions. `append` doesn't behave like that.

You need to format that data as one string. [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) would be the simplest way:

```
employees.append(f"Employee {emp_name} worked {num1} hours, and are paid {num2} $ per hour."
                 f"Making your salary {num1 * num2} $")
```

Now one single string is being added to the list.

---

Also note that you'll need to make a similar change for the bit

```
employees.append(str("Employee", emp_name, "Worked ", num1, "hours, and are paid", num2,
                     "$ per hour. Making your salary",
                     num1 * num2, "$"))
```

`str` doesn't take that many arguments either.

I would advise you to slow down and test code as you go. Writing massive chunks when you aren't sure what even works will just leave you with headaches and hinder  your learning.